# How to create circular seekbar in Android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Can anyone guide me to make **circular seek bar** in android ?? is there any example to make seek bar round in shape rather then linear with images , have any one tried
Reference : https://lh4.ggpht.com/9qL2sQi6XQYBY2pvgsPyObYS3UM42kRw64ve-GacU3jqW0XTEhARkdCLpmYzzhRULk0r

Comment: I found a tutorial for one a while ago, it worked pretty well, but you need to change couple of things to get it to work on seek bar as you want. Here is the link to the web page - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/

Comment: I've developed and open sourced a Circular SeekBar for Android, which can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar).

Comment: https://github.com/milosmns/circular-slider-android
Wrote it a while back, use it if you find it useful. Issues are reported on the wiki page, go ahead with that too if you find some. Also all contributors are welcome :)

Comment: @milosmns how do you set the max on this circular seek bar to range from 0-50 only?

Comment: @A.Turner So there is no limit actually. You can see this comment: https://github.com/milosmns/circular-slider-android/issues/9#issuecomment-261930607
Basically you get a range from Pi to 2xPi (as in traditional math), and there I described what you can do to get a range [0..1] if you need that. [0..1] range is essentially the same as any range, just multiply by 50 if you need [0..50].

Answer (score 21):

Found another great example [here](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc) for curved seek bar. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to change to thumb drawable?

Comment: while its good answer, you need to post an example on how to use it. A link might be missing sometimes in the future.

Comment: It's a great library bot not compatible with AndroidX.. yet

Comment: Hello, this is great library but i required this with two thumbs like range seek bar have i had checked many example but did not found a perfect , ans range are also cure not circular , any help will be great appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3):

I made my own library [here](https://github.com/bikcrum/CircularRangeSlider-Android). **CircularRangeSlider**

Demo app here (Playstore): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bikcrum.circularrangesliderdemo

[image]

> Check it on, it might fit your need.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192). If the tool or library is not free-to-use, please also mention this in your answer.

Comment: Hello this is very great but i need it in curved and also ranges are not circular i mean when min can move over to max and max can move over min,, any help will be great appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom circular seek-bar with image.

```
  public class ClockSlider extends View implements DialModel.Listener {
        /* Display modes */
        public static final int CLOCK_SLIDER = 1;
        public static final int VOLUME_SLIDER = 2;
        public static final int VIBRATE_PICKER = 3;

        public static final boolean ENABLE_VIBRATE = false;
        private static final int INSETS = 6;
        private static final int MINUTES_PER_HALF_DAY = 100;

        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int centerX;
        private int centerY;
        private int diameter;
        private RectF innerCircle;
        private int displayMode = CLOCK_SLIDER;

        private Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
        private int startAngle = 90;
        private Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();

        /** minutes to shush. */
        private int minutes = 0;

        private Bitmap bgBitmap;
        private Bitmap fgBitmap;
        private Path clipPath = new Path();

        private DialModel model;
        private float luftRotation = 0.0f;
        private int totalNicks = 100;
        private int currentNick = 0;

        public ClockSlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            bgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.black_circle);
            fgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.blue_circle);
            setModel(new DialModel());
        }

        public final void setModel(DialModel model) {
            if (this.model != null) {
                this.model.removeListener(this);
            }
            this.model = model;
            this.model.addListener(this);

            invalidate();
        }

        public final DialModel getModel() {
            return model;
        }



        public Date getStart() {
            return start.getTime();
        }



        public int getMinutes() {
            return minutes;
        }

        public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
            if (minutes == this.minutes) {
                return; // avoid unnecessary repaints
            }
            this.minutes = minutes;
            end.setTimeInMillis(start.getTimeInMillis() + (this.minutes * 60 * 1000L));
            postInvalidate();
        }

    //  public final float getRotationInDegrees() {
    //      return (360.0f / totalNicks) * currentNick;
    //  }

        public Date getEnd() {
            return end.getTime();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            if (getWidth() != width || getHeight() != height) {
                width = bgBitmap.getWidth();
                height = bgBitmap.getHeight();
    //          width = getWidth();
    //          height = getHeight();
                centerX = width / 2;
                centerY = height / 2;

                diameter = Math.min(width, height) - (2 * INSETS);
                int thickness = diameter / 15;

                int left = (width - diameter) / 2;
                int top = (height - diameter) / 2;
                int bottom = top + diameter;
                int right = left + diameter;
    //          outerCircle = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
                int innerDiameter = diameter - thickness * 2;
    //          innerCircle = new RectF(left + thickness, top + thickness, left
    //           + thickness + innerDiameter, top + thickness + innerDiameter);

                innerCircle = new RectF(0, 0,width,height);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, null, innerCircle, null);
            }

            if (displayMode == CLOCK_SLIDER) {
                drawClock(canvas);
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
        /**
         * Draw a circle and an arc of the selected duration from start thru end.
         */
        private void drawClock(Canvas canvas) {
            int sweepDegrees = (minutes / 2) - 1;

            canvas.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, null, innerCircle, null);
            // the colored "filled" part of the circle
            drawArc(canvas, startAngle, sweepDegrees);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDialPositionChanged(DialModel sender, int nicksChanged) {
            luftRotation = (float) (Math.random() * 1.0f - 0.5f);
            invalidate();
        }

        private void drawArc(Canvas canvas, int startAngle, int sweepDegrees) {
            if (sweepDegrees <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            clipPath.reset();
            clipPath.moveTo(innerCircle.centerX(), innerCircle.centerY());
            clipPath.arcTo(innerCircle, startAngle + sweepDegrees, -sweepDegrees);
    //      clipPath.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

            canvas.drawBitmap(fgBitmap, null, innerCircle, null);

            invalidate();
        }

        /**
         * Accept a touches near the circle's edge, translate it to an angle, and
         * update the sweep angle.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int touchX = (int) event.getX();
            int touchY = (int) event.getY();
            int newDisplayMode = displayMode;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                newDisplayMode = CLOCK_SLIDER;
            }

            int distanceFromCenterX = centerX - touchX;
            int distanceFromCenterY = centerY - touchY;
            int distanceFromCenterSquared = distanceFromCenterX * distanceFromCenterX + distanceFromCenterY * distanceFromCenterY;
            float maxSlider = (diameter * 1.3f) / 2;
            float maxUpDown = (diameter * 0.8f) / 2;

            /*
             * Convert the angle into a sweep angle. The sweep angle is a positive
             * angle between the start angle and the touched angle.
             */
    //       if (distanceFromCenterSquared < (maxSlider * maxSlider)) {
            float x1 = bgBitmap.getWidth(), x2 = bgBitmap.getHeight(), y1 = bgBitmap
                    .getWidth(), y2 = bgBitmap.getHeight();
            if ((touchX <= x1 && touchX <= x2)  && (touchY <= y1 && touchY <= y2)) {
                int angle = pointToAngle(touchX, touchY);
                angle = 360 + angle - startAngle;
                int angleX2 = angle * 2;
                angleX2 = roundToNearest15(angleX2);
                if (angleX2 > 720) {
                    angleX2 = angleX2 - 720; // avoid mod because we prefer 720 over
                }
                if (angle <= 364) {
                    angleX2 = 0;
                }
    //          if (angleX2 > 720 || angleX2 < 400) {
    //              return false;
    //          }
                setMinutes(angleX2);
                model.rotate(Integer.valueOf("" + Math.round((angleX2 / 5.4))));
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }


        public int getProgress(){
            return minutes;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            // Don't use the full screen width on tablets!
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            float maxWidthInches = 2.3f;

            width = Math.min(width, (int) (maxWidthInches * metrics.densityDpi));
            height = Math.min(height, (int) (width * 0.7f));

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the number of degrees (0-359) for the given point, such that 3pm
         * is 0 and 9pm is 180.
         */
        private int pointToAngle(int x, int y) {

            if (x >= centerX && y < centerY) {
                double opp = x - centerX;
                double adj = centerY - y;
                return 270 + (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(opp / adj));
            } else if (x > centerX && y >= centerY) {
                double opp = y - centerY;
                double adj = x - centerX;
                return (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(opp / adj));
            } else if (x <= centerX && y > centerY) {
                double opp = centerX - x;
                double adj = y - centerY;
                return 90 + (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(opp / adj));
            } else if (x < centerX && y <= centerY) {
                double opp = centerY - y;
                double adj = centerX - x;
                return 180 + (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(opp / adj));
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        /**
         * Rounds the angle to the nearest 7.5 degrees, which equals 15 minutes on a
         * clock. Not strictly necessary, but it discourages fat-fingered users from
         * being frustrated when trying to select a fine-grained period.
         */
        private int roundToNearest15(int angleX2) {
            return ((angleX2 + 8) / 15) * 15;
        }

    }
```