# how to set progress bar with rounded starting point in android layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-design-library

I am trying to create a progress bar using default progress bar given in android , I achieved 80% of that required design but i cannot find a code to finish the required design.

this is a required design

[given design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU1jx.jpg)
i need to bring the rounded part [highlighted in blue ] in my progress bar

[finished design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coWBO.jpg)

xml code

```
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/ww_progress_bar"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/circular_shape"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />
```

KT class

```
        binding.wwProgressBar.visibility = VISIBLE
        binding.wwProgressBar.setProgress(40)
        binding.wwProgressBar.max = progressMax
```

is it possible to bring the required design? can anyone help to finish this design?

Comment: Create a custom thumb for your progressbar.

Comment: any sample code you have?

Comment: Or best way is you can use circular seekbar.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678262/how-to-create-circular-seekbar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you need to use seek bar for it

use custom thumb for it

or

for easy implementation

you can use gihub library

https://github.com/tankery/CircularSeekBar

Answer (score 0):

you should set `thumb` in your `ProgressBar`

```
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
```

you can use this [link](https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/Circular-Progress-bar-with-Thumb) for more information